# Invariant violation, objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have checked many similar questions and haven't found a solution yet, I have a simple array and want to map to display

```
var tt = [
       {
         "age_range": {
           "max": 20,
           "min": 18,
          },
          "city": "San Francisco",
          "first_name": "Carol",
          "gender": "female",
          "id": "sfdf",
          "infinite": "cc",
          "last_name": "Smithberg",
          "locale": "en_US",
          "name": "Carol Albbhgfefjahc Smithberg",
          "option": "Option 3",
          "picture": {
            "data": {
              "height": 960,
              "is_silhouette": true,
              "url": "https://url",
              "width": 1524,
            },
          },
          "sub": "New",
          "uid": "dfee",
          "updated_time": "2017-10-31T23:52:44+0000",
          "verified": false,
       }
    ]

    return tt.map((others, index) =>
      <View key={others.infinite}>
        <Text>{others.sub}</Text>
      </View>
    );
```

I'm getting the error: Invariant violation, objects are not valid as a React child (found object with keys {_40, _65, _55, _72}) If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

`{other.sub}` definitely is a string, and I also tried

```
return tt.map(({ ...others }, index) =>
  <View key={others.infinite}>
    <Text>{others.sub}</Text>
  </View>
 );
```

and got the same error, the most promising [solution](https://github.com/cht8687/react-listview-sticky-header/issues/6) I've found insists I pass as an `{...item}` and then access as a `props.{property}`, however I don't fully understand this, how do I solve this please?

Comment: I've tried your code and it gives me no error and outputs `cc`. Where are you rending `tt.map` in your code?

Comment: Inside render() { }, this is React Native btw

Comment: Please provide your full code. It's working fine on my device.

Comment: You can check it here: https://snack.expo.io/rJDHBFiXf

Comment: Thanks, I'll ask permission as it's proprietary, this code was working very fine before as it is for you, then it stopped and started showing the error, tried refreshing expo to no avail

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error, when  i used this

```
render = async () => {
```

instead of this

```
render() {
```