# Unable to display promise data inside a method in render

Tags: reactjs

I realize I can't return objects in a react render but I'm having a problem figuring out how to do this.

Error message:

```
Invariant violation, objects are not valid as a React child error
```

My method:

```
displayListItemComponent = item => {

    return this.getConcernsDB(item.values)
    .then(returnedConcerns => {
        if(returnedConcerns.length) {
          returnedConcerns.forEach(el => {
            return(el.name);
          })
        }
      }
    )
}
```

Partial render:

```
<CollapseBody>
  { el.details.map(item => (
    this.displayListItemComponent(item)
  ))}
</CollapseBody>
```

Here I am trying to return `el.name` from `displayListItemComponent`
I am attempting to return `displayListItemComponent` in my react render.
My assumption was that by returning the function `this.getConcernsDB` that it would chain down and it would return `el.name`.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: You have this code in your render method? Thats not gonna work since its doing async operation and returning a promise. Your render method must be synchronous.

Comment: First time I came across a question having the exact same title as another: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48091884/invariant-violation-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child

Comment: @bad_coder: is the other question similar enough that any of those answers would help here.  Also: the reason the title was the same, is that that was the *exact* text of an error message. Exact error message quotes should not be altered (I restored it) - find another way to make the title unique.  However, if the new question is a "duplicate", the new question should instead be "flagged" and reported as a "duplicate" already having an answer on SO.  Having many answers to a question is fine, but it's best to have them cataloged under the same post, if the question is essentially the same.

Comment: @FabricioG if you have an error message from your code, it's a good idea to state that you got an error message, and SO guidelines request that you explicitly include error messages in the body of your question.  Generally, we format error messages using "quote formatting" (ie prepend the line to begin with a `>`).

Comment: @SherylHohman ok got it I’ll change it

Comment: @SherylHohman I understand your reasoning because I thought the same, in this case albeit it's the same error message I think the cause of the error is different...A fair comparison would be "segmentation fault" in C Ansi which can have a million different causes resulting in one same error message. Hence, I do not think it's a duplicate (because addressing the issue will require a different solution) and thus there's no reason to flag it as a duplicate.

Comment: @bad_coder: NP. I wasn't sure, so I didn't flag, just left it as a general heads up comment.  Thanks for checking it out and confirming. Yes, I've run into mssgs that can have wildly different causes! I also dunno if there's a title that could better describe this issue - error mssgs are often such a good search term :-o

Comment: @SherylHohman no problem. I have a 15:1 edit suggestion ratio approval, half the rejects were merge conflicts the SO community system didn't accept...But one of my edit rejections was indeed your zeal in keeping with high standards of revision. So I do get a kick of us having interacted in this instance :) . Yes, the solution this time will be rephrasing the tittle once a cause has been pinpointed and including the error msg in the body. Cheers :)

Comment: @bad_coder FYI, in *this* case, I accepted your edit (so you got the points)! All your other edits were substantive, helpful, and you didn't leave out anything glaring. Title was a close judgement call, and not entirely obvious that "are" was part of an error message. It was a good edit ! We all go through that learning curve. Glad to have you on board. Also, thanks for keeping standards high :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). [Render](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render) should be synchronous and have no side effects (e.g. it should only return allowed values from props and state). Therefore you need to store your data in [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), and render elements from state

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. Also what does `el.name` contain?

```
displayListItemComponent =(props) => {
    const {item} = props;
    const [data, setData] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
      // i see you did this.getConcernsDB. where is it coming from?
       getConcernsDB(item.values)
    .then(returnedConcerns => {

        setData(returnedConcerns.values(el => el.name))
    )

    }, [])

    if(!data) return <SomeLoadingSpinner />

    // now you have access to the names in `data` variable. Return whatever component you want using the `data`
  }
```